# How to wrap a UILabel within a prototype cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a Table View with the following Prototype Cell:

[image]

I want the text of the UILabel labeled "Description" to wrap onto a new line if the texts exceeds the UILabel's width.

The UILabel has the following Attributes:

[image]

However, it doesn't work...Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have added fixed height label. you have to atleast increase it's height. Attributes is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the bottom constraint on the label, it is causing the label to have a fixed height that is hiding any wrapped lines. Everything else is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; what should I adjust it to?

Comment: Just drag the bottom handle on the label's frame (as pictured in your screenshot) further towards the bottom of the cell, then go to `Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Selected Views -> Update Constraints`

Comment: I reduced the size of the bottom constraint and it works! Thanks @Wes!

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 issues in you auto layout constraints

If u have given fixed height to Description label then it can create problem

Secondly if u have given fixed height to image and bottom constraint to that image then also your label will not take the desired height

Please check this 2 constraint and let me know if u need any help

Comment: I didn't give the label a fixed height constraint; I just pinned it on the left, right, top and bottom.

Comment: There are no constraints on the Image View.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Moin :)